# Quasicompact quasiaffine classical schemes are nonconnectively-affine

Tags: homotopy-theory, derived-algebraic-geometry, ring-spectra

In [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/268656/136523) to [What is the relationship between connective and nonconnective derived algebraic geometry?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/268614/what-is-the-relationship-between-connective-and-nonconnective-derived-algebraic) I learned that any quasicompact open subscheme of an affine scheme is affine in the sense of nonconnective spectral algebraic geometry. Let me try to give this argument in my own words: let $X = \operatorname{Spec} A$ for an ordinary commutative ring $A$ and let $i : U \subseteq X$ be quasi-compact. We can find a finite cover of $U$ by distinguished opens, i.e. $U = D(a_1) \cup D(a_2) \cup \dotsb \cup D(a_m)$. Then the koszul complex $K = K(a_1,\dotsc,a_m)$ is a perfect complex with support $X \setminus U$. The derived pushforward $\mathbb{R}f_* : D_{\text{qc}}(U) \to D_{\text{qc}}(X) = D(A)$ is fully faithful, with left adjoint $\mathbb{L} f^*$, and embeds $D_{\text{qc}}(U)$ as the right orthogonal complement of $K$. Since $\mathbb{L} f^*$ is strong monoidal its right adjoint acquires a lax monoidal structure, and so the localization functor $\mathbb{R}f_* \circ \mathbb{L}f^*$ is (symmetric) lax monoidal. The image of the base ring $A$ under this is then a (not-necessarily-connective) $E_{\infty}$-algebra $B$ over $A$, whose category of modules may be identified with $D(U)$. The underlying complex carrying the $E_{\infty}$-structure can be calculated as the cofiber of $\mathbb{R}\Gamma_I(A) \to A$. We could also calculate $B$ via the sheaf condition for the structure sheaf of $\operatorname{Spec} A$ on the cover $\{D(a_1),\dotsc,D(a_m)\}$.

Now it makes sense to me that the functor points and the tt-category of $B$ are correct, but I don't see how the spectrum actually gives the right topological space. I tried to work this out in the specific example of $\mathbb{A}^2_{\mathbb{C}} \setminus \{(0, 0)\} \subseteq \mathbb{A}^2_{\mathbb{C}}$ (see the [other answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/268614/what-is-the-relationship-between-connective-and-nonconnective-derived-algebraic/268631#268631) to [the linked question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/268614/what-is-the-relationship-between-connective-and-nonconnective-derived-algebraic)) and got confused. In that case we have $\pi_0(B) \cong \mathbb{C}[x, y]$, and my understanding is that the spectrum of an $\mathbb{E}_{\infty}$-ring is just the spectrum of its $\pi_0$-ring as a topological space (and then we equip it with a certain structure sheaf using the higher information). So in this case it would seem that the underlying/truncated ordinary schemes of $\operatorname{Spec} B$ and $U$ have different points. What gives? Is there something sneaky going on which allows $\operatorname{Spec} B$ and the open subscheme $U$ to be isomorphic in the $(\infty, 1)$-category of nonconnective spectral schemes?

Comment: Corollary 1.1.6.3 in HA says a nonconnective spectral scheme is affine iff its underlying scheme is affine, which is not making me any less confused!

Comment: I think this is just a matter of definitions: a quasi-affine spectral scheme is non-connectively affine in the sense that you explain (this is discussed in Section 2.4 in SAG), but not according to the definition of "affine nonconnective spectral scheme" in SAG.

Comment: I'm still confused, according to the answers I linked we actually have that $\operatorname{Spec} B$ is isomorphic to the open subset (bc it has the right functor of points or is an appropriate pushout). So is the inconsistent defintion $\operatorname{Spec} B$ itself? Section 2.4 is clarifying though, thanks

Comment: Yes, Spec is used to mean different things: $B$ and the non-affine open $U$ have the same functor of points, but $\pi_0(B)$ and $U$ do not have the same underlying topological space.

Comment: But this is confusing to me because I thought the yoneda lemma implies two (derived) schemes with the same functor of points are isomorphic

Comment: It does not, because the test objects are always connective.